# How to change the number format of a column in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use a user selection to alter the number format of a column inside that selection. The number format I am attempting to change it to is Accounting. The code I have tried is below.

```
Dim r As Range
Dim s As String
s = Selection.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlA1, RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
r = Range(s).Columns("G")
r.NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
```

I know for sure that String s gets the correct string value of the user selection. Getting the range of just column G is what seems to be incorrect.

Comment: do you always want to format column `G` (the absolute column G) or do you want to format the `7th` column away from the user selection, or do you want to format the entire column of the user selection?

Comment: The user must select columns A:n through N:n, I want only column G:n to be changed in that selection. So it's like a range inside of a selected area that I need to be changed. I should mention that the range r's value is nothing when it executes.

Comment: okay, so it's the 7th column from the left most column selected in the range? (column G is 7 columns from column A in a spreadsheet)?

Comment: Yes, it is the 7th column then. Sorry, I'm sorta new to vba and not exactly sure what was meant by "absolute column G".

Comment: posting an answer in a moment ... when I said `absolute column G` I meant the literal column G on the spreadsheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

```
Dim rSel As Range, rCol As Range

Set r = Selection
If r.Columns.Count > 6 Then 'make sure there are even 7 columns

    Set rCol = r.Columns(7) 'Columns("G")
    rCol.NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"

End If
```

Comment: It isn't working. rCol is getting the correct column (column 7, or "G" in my case), but the number format still remains the same (which is currency).

Comment: @BrettComardelle - I used the `NumberFormat` you provided in your original question. to get the accounting format, see my edited answer for the format to use.

Comment: I added rCol.Select and noticed that rCol is assigned to a row much lower on the spreasheet than what was originally selected.

Comment: @BrettComardelle - try this simpler version in my edited answer (again). You're original approach was good, except you did not have the correct `NumberFormat`. Keep in mind that this will only format the 7th column when there are *at least* 7 columns selected. To remove this check, comment out the `If` block.